# WebClientException on tweet parsing @ WP7

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7

i made an app to look at people's tweet, anyway, i tried the following code to parse it

```
MainViewModel mvm = new MainViewModel();
mvm.Items.Clear();

XDocument xTweets = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
foreach (var tweets in xTweets.Descendants("status"))
{
    ItemViewModel ivm2 = new ItemViewModel()
    {
        TweetImage = tweets.Element("user").Element("profile_image_url").Value,
        TweetSender = tweets.Element("user").Element("screen_name").Value,
        Tweet = tweets.Element("text").Value,
    };
   Items.Add(ivm2);
}
```

and the xaml:

```
<Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{Binding TweetImage}" Margin="12,0,9,0"/>
<StackPanel Width="311">                                    
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TweetSender}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>    
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tweet}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

the app run for a while on the emulator, but after 30 seconds it returned into a WebClientException. i don't know which line is wrong and the debugger doesn't tell the details of the error.

Answer (score 1):

```
e.Result
```

Is most likely your error. I'm assuming your doing this in a WebClient Finished event

Do the following:

```
MainViewModel mvm = new MainViewModel();
mvm.Items.Clear();

if (e.Error == null && e.Result != null)
{
    XDocument xTweets = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
    foreach (var tweets in xTweets.Descendants("status"))
    {
        ItemViewModel ivm2 = new ItemViewModel()
        {
            TweetImage = tweets.Element("user").Element("profile_image_url").Value,
            TweetSender = tweets.Element("user").Element("screen_name").Value,
            Tweet = tweets.Element("text").Value,
        };
        Items.Add(ivm2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, dude. My reputation point isn't enough to vote it up :'(